# Integrate product of two Gaussians

Tags: integration

I have two Gaussians $N_1(x; \mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $N_2(x, x'; \mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ over variables $x$ and $x'$. Both $x$ and $x'$ are $d$-dimensional. I want to compute the integral $\int N_1(x'; \mu_1, \Sigma_1) N_2(x, x'; \mu_2, \Sigma_2) dx'$. I don't know how to do it because the two functions are over different variables. Perhaps by decomposing the covariance matrices into 4 parts $\Sigma^{xx}$, $\Sigma^{xx'}$, $\Sigma^{x'x}$ and $\Sigma^{x'x'}$? Can anyone help me compute it?

Comment: Nope, it's multidimensional over x and x', i.e. 2d-dimensional.

Comment: Ok so what you are saying is that $N_2(z) = N(z;\mu_2,\Sigma_2)$ where $z = (x_1,\ldots, x_d,x_1',\ldots,x_d')$ right? Decomposing the covariance matrix in block form seems to be a good idea. Then you can try to complete the square in the exponential after combining the two terms in the integrand and evaluate it as standard gaussian integrals. Something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) might be useful.